# How to pass variable from foreach to view?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass a variable from `foreach` to my view. So I can access this using in my select form. Because I have two tables M:M relationship between **departments** and **user**. I need to get all the `department_name` where the `user_id` belong. For me able to send a data via `department_name` Here what I did please take a look.

DB Diagram:

[image: SC]

**department_user**

[image: SC]

As you can see here `user_id` is the id of the user and `document_id` is where the users belong.

Model:

Department:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\User', 'department_user');
}
```

User:

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Department', 'department_user');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    $departmentRecipient = DB::table('departments')->get();
    foreach ($departmentRecipient as $department)
    {
        $department->users = DB::table('department_user')
            ->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)
            ->pluck('user_id');
    }

    return view('document.create')->with('department', $department);
}
```

I'm getting all the users_id when I die and dump my variable `departmentRecipient`.

[image: SC]

View:

```
<div class = "form-group">
    <label for = "recipient" class = "control-label">Recipient:</label>     
    <select name = "recipient[]" multiple class = "form-control select2-multi" id = "myUserList">
        @foreach ($department as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->user_id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

</div>
```

I wanted to `foreach` the `$department` in my Controller to my select form. But it always says.

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\document\create.blade.php)

Goal:

[image: SC]

Comment: show whole controller code.

Comment: @mmmm I updated my post please see :)

Comment: You can't pass $department to view because it is in foreach loop. Solve by defining it before the loop. Btw, you don't need get user "too manually" like that.

Comment: @KmasterYC I thought I can pass `$department` from my foreach loop to my view. Any tips how can I solve this?

Comment: Oh. My mistake. But by that way. You get only last $department value. Did u set up relation between them?

Comment: @KmasterYC Why I can only get the last `$department` value? I updated my post please see my diagram.

Comment: Create a chat room. I'll help you to solve this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121187/discussion-between-francisunoxx-and-kmasteryc).

Comment: @KmasterYC Please click the chat link thanks!!

Comment: @Francisunoxx sorry, I couldn't understand your problem , could you explain what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @jaysingkar I wanted to get all the department with `user_id` so I can send data by department. I already close to my solution! :)

Comment: @Francisunoxx you got the solution ?

Comment: @jaysingkar Not yet. I'm still thinking can I passed the `$department` variable in my view. Can you help me?

Comment: sure... btw don't you think you should pass `departmentRecipient` instead of `department` in your ? since you have mentioned that `departmentRecipient` has the data you wanted

Comment: `$departmentRecipient = DB::table('departments')->with('users')->get();`

Comment: `return view('document.create')->with('department', $departmentRecipient );`

Comment: something like this

Comment: @jaysingkar If I pass `departmentRecipient` I'm just only getting the id of the department. I wanted to return my view like this. `<option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>` But when I choose one of the option. It should have a `user_id` inside.

Comment: @jaysingkar I tried your solution but it says `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121399/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-francisunoxx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following loop to iterate through the department users and add them to pivot table.

```
foreach($request->department as $departmentId) 
{ 
foreach(Department::find($departmentId->id)->users()->get() as $user1) //find the users belonging to the current department 
{ 
$document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $user1->id => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false ); 
} 
}
```

Also remove the following code form your `getDocuments()` as it is redundant:

```
foreach ($departmentRecipient as $department)
    {
        $department->users = DB::table('department_user')
            ->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)
            ->pluck('user_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `user_id` property in your dumped value of `$departmentRecipient` object, that is why you are getting the error you mentioned. However, there is a users array inside of `$departmentRecipient` object, which you made inside your `foreach` loop. You are plucking every `user_id` which are in individual department and setting in a property named `users` of `$departmentRecipient` object, and so you are getting an array inside `users` property. Here I have a solution for you,

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    $departmentRecipient = DB::table('departments')->get();
    $departmentUsers = array();
    foreach ($departmentRecipient as $department)
    {
        $users = DB::table('department_user')
            ->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)
            ->pluck('user_id');
        foreach ($users as $userId) {
            $departmentUsers[$userId] = $department->department_name;
        }
    }

    return view('document.create')->with('department', $department)->with('departmentUsers', $departmentUsers);
}
```

and inside of your view loop through the variable `$departmentUsers`, like this,

```
@foreach ($departmentUsers as $userId => $departmentName)
        <option value = "{{ $userId }}">{{ $departmentName }}</option>
@endforeach
```

This will work but as your department contains multiple users so you will get individual department name multiple time in your `select2` dropdown. If you share more of what is your goal by `select2` then may be I can help you to solve your problem in other way.

Moreover if you are interested to use of Eloquent then you can get rid of lots of `foreach` looping.

Comment: Hey I found your solution nice! But in your solution you only shows each user that has Department. How can I show in my select form each Department? :)

Comment: @Francisunoxx If you want to select users from each department then you have can do,
     ``foreach ($departmentRecipient as $department)
    {
        $users = DB::table('department_user')
            ->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)
            ->get(['user_id', 'user_name']);
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $department->users = array('user_id'=>$user->user_id, 'user_name'=>$user->user_name);
        }
    }``
and then in blade file do foreach as you did and then in optgroup put dept_name and foreach option through dept->users

Comment: I like your solution. But I wanted to select per Department that consist of many users. I know I'm already near to my answer. :)

Comment: @Francisunoxx You can not pass an array as value of option but I have more solution for you, you do ``foreach`` in your blade as you did and give value ``$department->id`` and then get the id in your method inside of Controller, where you post your data, and then get users by querying using that department id. Hope this will help you to get users by your selected department.

Comment: I get your point. Can you show some solution how can I get the id inside my Controller?

Comment: @Francisunoxx inside of your blade do,
``@foreach ($department as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>
@endforeach``
and then inside the method where you post your data do,
``$users=DB::table('department_user')
            ->where('department_id', '=', $department_id)
            ->pluck('user_id');``
here I think you use Request helper to receive requests so your $department_id will be $request->recipient. Also please remove name of select2 field as array. It will be single id, or if you want multiple select then thats okay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121218/discussion-between-francisunoxx-and-shafiuzzaman).

Comment: Please see my updated post. I elaborate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Francisunoxx I have given you the solution and you are almost close to it. I could not give enough explanation in comment because of character limitations, I could come to chat but I am busy now. Hope, I will be free after 10 hours from now. Knock me then, if you can't find the solution. :)

Comment: Sure! Thanks for giving a solution. Just comment here if your not busy. Thankyou! :)

Comment: Hey bro! I still didn't find a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: I knocked you in chat, knock me back.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can have multiple users against each department. So to make it work correctly with your forearch code. You need to make sure you are getting one user record against each depart. So modify following line of code in controller.

```
$department->users = DB::table('department_user')->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)->pluck('user_id');
```

But you want to display all users of department then you have to change foreach loop code into view.

Comment: What part am I wrong? I think I'm not getting the right user per department.

Comment: `@foreach ($department as $list)
@foreach ($list->users as $user)
            <option value = "{{ $user->id }}">{{ $list->department_name }}</option>
@endforeach
        @endforeach`

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

App/Department

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\User', 'department_user', 'user_id', 'department_id');
    }
```

App/User

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Department', 'department_user');
}
```

Controller

```
use App/User;

public function getDocuments($userId,User $User)
{
    $getSpecificUser = $User->with('departments')->find($userid);

    return view('document.create')->compact('getSpecificUser');
}
```

View

```
@foreach ($getSpecificUser as $getUser)
    @if(empty($getUser->departments) === false)
        @foreach ($getUser->departments as $departments)
            <option value = "{{ $getUser->id }}">{{ $departments->department_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't show `department_name` in my select form. Please see my updated post. I elaborate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you want to show the departments for specific users or for all users?

Comment: Yes I wanted to show the departments for specific users. But in my select form in will only show per Department not user per department.